# Can ASUS Prime B450M II work without dedicated graphics card or integrated graphics card?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, amd-ryzen, asus

I new to PC building. I have a ASUS Prime B450M II motherboard with AMD Ryzen 5 4500 CPU (without integrated graphics). Do I need a dedicated graphics card to use this build? I don't have gaming or graphics-intensive needs. Just basic usage, and some programming stuff.

Comment: Only you can determine if you need a display or not.  The system can boot without a dGPU or iGPU existing in the system.  There are tons of headless servers that exist.  The fact your usage case indicates your expecting to use it for "basic usage", that would suggest, having a display would be important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have integrated graphics then you need at least some kind of dedicated graphics, otherwise you have nothing that can output to a display in the first place.

There are plenty of relatively cheap low performance graphics card out there. A [GT 1030](https://www.amazon.co.uk/GEFORCE-GT-1030-2GHD4-LP/dp/B07CMH5F9R/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=geforce%20gt%201030) can be had for about £60 and there are some other cheap options out there but you're not likely to find newer stuff much cheaper, there hasn't exactly been much movement in the budget graphics card area recently due to improvements in integrated graphics.